# GzipStream blockwise compression results in a corrupted file

Tags: c#, .net-core, compression, gzip, gzipstream

I am trying to implement block-by-block compression using GzipStream class. .NET Core 3.1, Visual Studio 2019, Console App. My OS is Windows 10. I believe it should be possible because gzip files consist of independent blocks one after another as per format specification. But resulting files that I get are corrupted. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace GzipToMemoryStreamExample
{
class Program
{
    private static int blockSize;
    private static string sourceFileName = "e:\\SomeFolder\\SomeFile.ext";

    private static byte[] currentBlock;
    private static FileStream readingStream;
    private static FileStream writingStream;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter block size:");
        string blockSizeStr = Console.ReadLine();
        int.TryParse(blockSizeStr, out blockSize);

        readingStream = new FileStream(sourceFileName, FileMode.Open);
        string resultingFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(sourceFileName, ".gz");
        CreateAndOpenResultingFile(resultingFileName);
        while (ReadBlock())
        {
            byte[] processedBlock = ProcessBlock(currentBlock);
            writingStream.Write(processedBlock, 0, processedBlock.Length);
        }
        readingStream.Dispose();
        writingStream.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static bool ReadBlock()
    {
        bool result;
        int bytesRead;
        currentBlock = new byte[blockSize];
        bytesRead = readingStream.Read(currentBlock, 0, blockSize);
        result = bytesRead > 0;
        return result;
    }

    private static byte[] ProcessBlock(byte[] sourceData)
    {
        byte[] result;
        using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using var compressionStream = new GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
            compressionStream.Write(sourceData, 0, sourceData.Length);
            result = outputStream.ToArray();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void CreateAndOpenResultingFile(string fileName)
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            File.Delete(fileName);
        }
        writingStream = File.Create(fileName);
    }
}
}
```

When I look at resulting files I see that result somehow depends on block size I choose. if it's smaller than ~100 Kb, resulting "compressed" blocks are of 10 bytes size each, which leads to extremely small useless file. If size of block is greater than ~100 Kb, then the size of file becomes reasonably large, about 80% of the original, but still corrupted.
Also I checked the block headers and it turns out they're strange. OS is set to TOPS-20 (0x0a value), ISIZE at the end of block is always totally wrong.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Shouldn't the `using` for `GZipStream` have braces and enclose the `Write`?

Comment: This syntax is supported starting from C# 8:
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations

Comment: So the `using` is not closed until _after_ you grab the output. You have to close the stream before grabbing the output. Otherwise you will get a partial, invalid gzip stream.

Comment: Man that worked, thank you. Turned out so simple. Is it worth leaving it here?

Comment: Yes. You should leave it here, and you should answer your own question in that empty space below, including the code change that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved just with moving *result = outputStream.ToArray();* line out of the compressionStream using scope as Mark Adler suggested in the comments.

```
    private static byte[] ProcessBlock(byte[] sourceData)
    {
        byte[] result;
        using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var compressionStream = new GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                compressionStream.Write(sourceData, 0, sourceData.Length);
            }
            result = outputStream.ToArray();
        }
        return result;
    }
```